# Wrong background image positioning for image close to right border

Tags: html, css

If I want to use a background image positioned at 80% on the x-axis, and the image width is 30%, my understanding is that the image should be partially disappearing on the right side (starting at 80% and ending at 110% of the div's width). However, it seems that the browser decides to align the *right* side of the image at 80% - but if I changed 80 to 20 then it aligns the left side at 20%. This is really strange behavior and a problem for me.

Here's a fiddle to illustrate what I'm talking about:

https://jsfiddle.net/qzbrkbcz/2/

The first background image is correctly positioned and the second is right-aligned.

How do I make sure that background images always have their top left corner positioned at the `background-position` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background image will position itself according to it's own size. So if you want it to go out of the container, you'll have to use something like `background-position: 250% 100%;`

https://jsfiddle.net/maxpaj/qzbrkbcz/6/

Good luck :)

Comment: So basically I need to add the background image's width to the position x value IF the width + x are more than 100%.

Comment: Either you would have to use pixel values to determine the background position. Or calculate how big the image is relative to the container, then set the percentage value accordingly. I made a new fiddle with position determined by pixel values: https://jsfiddle.net/maxpaj/qzbrkbcz/7/